# Do people who serially commit heinous crimes (murder, rape, etc...) know that what they are doing is wrong?

Tags: criminology, death

Do serial killers and other heinous-crime-comitters know that they are committing horrible acts that are wrong, but just do so anyway because it fulfills them somehow? Or do they view their actions as 'right'?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. What makes you think otherwise? Have you read anything about it in journals or scientific books or websites?

Comment: Related: [How would a psychopath deem their actions?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/13847/7001)

Comment: I think the answer to this question might depend upon precisely what you mean by "right" and "wrong". IMHO, conscience is an emergent phenomenon which requires certain conditions to be exist in order to emerge. (1) the ability to feel strong pain signals. Psychopaths do not. (2) the ability to feel affective empathy. Narcissists do not. https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/25146/8423

Comment: What is 'right' and what is 'wrong'? Its all perspective. For example, a policeman might think you jay walking is wrong, because it might be against the law however many people might simply look at it as crossing the road and think the law is stupid. Therefore, they would not deem their actions to be wrong.
Now in the case of a serial killer etc. they generally have a few reasons they do what they do, but as far as knowing whether its right or wrong? My view is, they know its wrong according to societies norms but they don't care. So in their mind, its not wrong, its just illegal.